# php mysqli mysql databe adding new values

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update

so i get error when trying to add new values to my database, the code so far:

```
<?php 

include 'config.php';
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","labas_main","1Ym9ZnPP","labas_main");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

        $field1 = isset( $_POST['darbuotojas']) ? $_POST['darbuotojas'] : "";
        $field2 = isset( $_POST['objektas']) ? $_POST['objektas'] : "";
        $field3 = isset( $_POST['dirbo']) ? $_POST['dirbo'] : "";
        //atstatom busena i INT kintamaji
            if ($field3 == "ne") {
            $field3=0;
            }
                elseif ($field3 == "taip") {
                $field3=1;
                }
            else $field3=2;
        $field4 = isset( $_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : "";






            mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO 'suvestine' ('atsiskaitymas', 'darbuotojo_ID', 'data', 'objekto_ID')
                                VALUES ('".$field3."', '".$field1."', '".$field4."', '".$field2."')";




?>
```

The error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/labas/domains/labasgas.lt/public_html/crm/suvestine_add.php on line 30

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong: `quotes` and missing `)`

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO suvestine (atsiskaitymas, darbuotojo_ID, data, objekto_ID) VALUES ('".$field3."', '".$field1."', '".$field4."', '".$field2."')");
```

Comment: Thank you very much Schellingerht. Need to take a rest for today :)))

Comment: Perfect! Please mark the right answer ;-)